# Has FileVault crashed?

Tags: macos, performance, filevault

I've just enabled FileVault 2 on my mid-2012 MacBook Air and am worried it has crashed.

I've entered all the details and clicked "Restart" and now have a greyed out System Preference pane with a spinner.

If I try and manually restart from the Apple menu I'm told that System Preferences are stopping a restart.

How long should this stage take? Is it safe to hit the power button? I know the encryption occurs after a restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after no action after an hour I restarted and was presented with a non-bootable SSD.

Luckily the task immediately previous to enabling FileVault was to run a backup so that was restored overnight...

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me. went to back up 2000 photos with file vault and restarted my air and now i cant get past apple load screen. i held shift for a while and it had a bar that was loading but when it finished my air just shut down and it keeps happening. 
scared ive lost all my photos when the point of the vault is to protect them, fml! 
Help!